# How to make an array of pointers and make the user enter the size of it?

Tags: windows-10, iomanip, setw

I want to make an array, and inside this array there are pointers, like this:
`int *arrp[size];` and I want the user to enter the size of it.
I tried to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   int size;
   cout << "Enter the size of the array of pointers" << endl;
   cin >> size;
   int *arrp[size];
   
   return 0;
}
```

but this doesn't work.
I also tried to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   int size;
   cout << "Enter the size of the array of pointers" << endl;
   cin >> size;
   int* arrp[] = new int[size];
   
   return 0;
}
```

also doesn't work, can someone help?

The error of the first code is that the size must be constant, I tried to fix that by writing the 2nd code but it gives an error for the word "new" in line 9:
E0520   initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object
and another error for the size in the same line:
C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int *[]'

Comment: Can you give us a bit more details how "doesn't work" is showing up? Error message, behaviour, etc - you do not use the array in your code, so what is the expected behaviour and what the observed?

Comment: here it is the array in line 9, ``` int *arrp[size]; ``` ( I want to make an array of pointers) The error of the first code is that the size must be constant, I tried to fix that by writing the 2nd code but gives an error for the word "new" in line 9: 
E0520 initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object
and another error for the size in the same line:
C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int *[]'

Comment: The only way it worked for me was `int** arrp = new int*[size];` but cannot explain why you can't use `int*[]` in the declaration, so not posting it as an answer. But as an array is referenced with a pointer, you cannot assign an array of int (`new int[bla]`) to an array of pointers.

Comment: Thanks, that was beneficial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an array of pointers you should type: `int** arr = new int*[size]`
we type 2 stars '*', the first mean a pointer to an integer, the second means a pointer to the pointer to the integer, and then we make a place in the memory for those pointers by typing `= new int*[size]`, you can use this as a 2D array that stored in the heap (not the stack) go to this website to know the difference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/.
to know more about how to use an array of pointers to a pointer to an integers you can see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNgUMA_Ur0U&ab_channel=TheCherno.